# How to show modified header when I fetch data from DataTable in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table 'tbTest2' and to modify this table I use this SQL

```
 select v.q,
       sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as val_1,
       sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2,
       sum(case when val = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as val_3
from tbTest2 t cross apply
     (values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)
where t.userType = 'student'
group by v.q;
```

After that, I get this table:

[image]

Now I want to show it with modified header. For this, I use for

**.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTable">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" Width="50px" Wrap="True" Text='<%# Eval("q")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" Width="30px" Wrap="True" Text='<%# Eval("val_1")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" Width="30px" Wrap="True" Text='<%# Eval("val_2")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="3">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" Width="30px" Wrap="True" Text='<%# Eval("val_3")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

.cs

```
 SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapterTable = new SqlDataAdapter
                ("select v.q," +
                "sum(case when val = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as val_1," +
                "sum(case when val = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as val_2," +
                "sum(case when val = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as val_3 " +
                "from tbTest2 t cross apply" +
                "(values ('q1', t.q1), ('q2', t.q2), ('q3', t.q3)) v(q, val)" +
                "where t.userType = 'student'" +
                "group by v.q;", con);
            DataTable dataTableTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapterTable.Fill(dataTableTable);
            gvTable.DataSource = dataTableTable;
            gvTable.DataBind();
```

But I face this problem where every  column create two times with modified and raw header

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to microsoft docs,
When the AutoGenerateColumns property is set to true, an AutoGeneratedField object is automatically created for each field in the data source(by default it sets to true). Each field is then displayed as a column in the GridView control in the order that the fields appear in the data source.

In your case,

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvTable" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ...>
```